# Is hover from jquery to backbone code

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to translate this into backbone event model, avoiding using directly jquery.

`$(".class").is(":hover")`

What I have tried in my view is register an event (mouseenter, mouseleave), but seems that the events are being intercepted before by another component probably because it have stopPropagation or for an uncertain reason I don't receive it. I need to have something like this.

```
if($(".class").is(":hover")){
//execute this code.
}
```

What I tried to do is using event handlers to intercept the hover on a specific element change a flag, and change the condition to use that flag.

```
if(flag){
//execute this code.
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) javascript event.

If the event bubbling is stopped by `stopPropagation`, rethink using `stopPropagation` as it causes all sort of problems.

Here's a simple backbone view using the event.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "mouseover .specific-element": "onMouseOver"
    },

    onMouseOver: function(e) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```